# Unique id of page request in sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to cache one very important thing during one page cycle. 
I want to use a unique request id like correlation id.

How can I get such an id in SharePoint?

Comment: Why would you want to cache keyed on CorrelationID? Its unique for each page request so whats the point of caching something that will never be used again?

Comment: One page loads in different controls a lot of same data. So i need to cache it. And i want to use CorrelationID to or something for this purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this excellent blogpost for details about using the SharePoint correlation ID: http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Working-with-SharePoint-2010-Correlation-ID-in-PowerShell-and-code.aspx

Update:
This is how he does it:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
public static extern uint EventActivityIdControl(uint controlCode, ref Guid activityId);
public const uint EVENT_ACTIVITY_CTRL_GET_ID = 1;
```

And then use it in code like below, perhaps in a catch statement:

```
Guid g = Guid.Empty;
EventActivityIdControl(EVENT_ACTIVITY_CTRL_GET_ID, ref g);
this.Controls.Add(new Label { 
    Text = string.Format("An error occurred with correlation id {0}", g)
});
```

Comment: See my updated answer for code. Can you see how to use it now?